# .htaccess Rewriting Tomcat Server

Tags: .htaccess, tomcat, rewrite, railo

I am writing a website using Railo. My code is to be deployed on a Railo Server running on Tomcat, overlayed on a regular Apache+PHP server.

I need to send all requests to `http://subdomain.myserver.co.uk/` and its child files to the directory `/public_html/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/subdomain/` directory.

I defined a subdomain in cPanel, with the document root as `/public_html/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/subdomain/`, but still requests to `http://subdomain.myserver.co.uk/` display files in `/public_html/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/`. I can view my files if I request `http://subdomain.myserver.co.uk/subdomain/`

I've been fiddling with the .htaccess files for quite some time now, but I'm stuck

Is there any way I can do what I'm trying to achieve, or am I resigned to get those pages using `http://subdomain.myserver.co.uk/subdomain/`

Answer (score 1):

Put the following into /public_html/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} enterprise.myserver.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) /public_html/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/lfEnterprise$1
```

Here the target of the RewriteRule is a filesystem path, not a URL as is more common.  RewriteRule will accept either, and figure out which one is meant.  Please see the [RewriteRule documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for that and more.

Comment: Where do I put this htaccess? in the ROOT directory?

Comment: Edited to clarify that.

Comment: So let me demystify things a bit... My subdomain is enterprise.myserver.co.uk but my app resides in `/public_html/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/lfEnterprise` Also this is a Tomcat server overlayed on an Apache, so please keep that in mind.

Comment: Edited again.  I don't know Tomcat, but I don't think it matters here.

Comment: Edited again to remove one of the RewriteConds.